# How to put a conditional space between words?

Tags: javascript

There is an object storing translation strings. The translation string can contain {user} noted placeholder to be used in the logic code:

```
const translations = {
   ...
   'outOfQuota': 'Dear {userName}, you are out of space!'
}
```

The logic of the code that displays the message should show it when we have a userName:

```
Dear Jack, you are out of space!
```

However, there might be situations, when the user is logged in, but the user object is undefined or null. Also, sometimes userName can be undefined.

In such situation a slightly different message should be showed:

```
Dear, you are out of space!
```

Currently, I have solved it by removing the space between 'Dear' and the placeholder:

```
const translations = {
   ...
   'outOfSpace': 'Dear{userName}, you are out of space!'
}
```

And writing a conditional logic to place the space and a name, or an empty string:

```
// Long code that results in setting:
const user.userName = 'John';
...
const userName = user && user.userName ? ` ${user.userName}` : ``; // (4)
const message = translations.outOfSpace.replace('{userName}', userName);
```

However, I don't like how line 4 and translation sentence looks like. It is hard to read.

Is there any way to make it look better?

Comment: One small improvement would be to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) on the `user && user.userName` check, to just become `user?.userName`

Comment: Do you want a function methods or class. I have solutions to that

Comment: I think it would be the case to have different entries in the translations object for the messages that can be delivered with or without some infos.

Comment: I'd start by re-writing this message. Two general rules for messages an application makes: 1. Avoid an exclamation mark. Messages usually aren't exciting enough for that. Imagine you go to work or something and somebody comes at you *shouting* "Your drawer is full!". That's roughly equivalent to what adding an exclamation mark is. People are likely to notify you in less excited fashion and even tone. 2. Avoid addressing the user in a familial manner. "Dear John" sounds weird in a lot of cases. A program isn't my friend. It just needs to tell me something, not pretend it respects me.

Comment: Why you don't implement a function if you only want a conditions detecting when the arg is null or undefined

Comment: @Vlaz interesting point, however it does not solve the problem. And it indicates we limit a feature because of a wrong reason

Comment: @Vince anything that is nicer

Comment: @TomaszSmykowski it solves the core of the problem which is a very bad user message. The feature you want is *good* message, correct? Because the current ones aren't. "Dear, you are out of space!" isn't just an issue of spacing - it fundamentally changes the message intention amplifying the *already wrongfully worrying tone*. The question, at its technical core, is fine. However, the problem you're trying to solve shouldn't be the technical one.

Comment: @VLAZ The message serves as an example, and yes, it may be better. But it is not the point of the question. As the title says: "How to put a conditional space between words?"

Comment: @TomaszSmykowski as you can see, I'm mentioning this as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a **function**.
You can make it a one line code in **es6**

```
const translations = {
   ...,
   outOfQuota: function(name){
   return `Dear${name ? ` ${name}`: ""}, you are out of space!`
 }
}
```

you can also add a **default val** in the arg when its undefined

Comment: I just want to point out that "Dear, you are out of space!" sounds quite alarming and not at all comparable to "Dear John, you are out of space!". Both of these are not very good messages for the user, though but *just* omitting the username changes the message a lot.

Comment: The sentence has to be placed as a string in the translation file. It can not be a function there. Because translators have to receive it as strings

Comment: @VLAZ The message serves as an example, and yes, it may be better. But it is not the point of the question. As the title says: "How to put a conditional space between words?"